# Spring Boot - Test for controller fails with 404 code

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, controller

I want to write a test for controller. Here is test snippet:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(WeatherStationController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MockConfig.class)
public class WeatherStationControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private IStationRepository stationRepository;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnCorrectStation() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/stations")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

controller code snippet:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "stations")
public class WeatherStationController {

    @Autowired
    private WeatherStationService weatherService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<WeatherStation> getAllWeatherStations() {
        return weatherService.getAllStations();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public WeatherStation getWeatherStation(@PathVariable String id) {
        return weatherService.getStation(id);
    }
```

MockConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "edu.lelyak.repository")
public class MockConfig {

    //**************************** MOCK BEANS ******************************

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public WeatherStationService weatherServiceMock() {
        WeatherStationService mock = Mockito.mock(WeatherStationService.class);
        return mock;
    }
```

Here is error stack trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :200
Actual   :404
```

I can get what is wrong here.
***How to fix test for controller?***

Comment: Had a similar issue when I renamed the package and forgot to change in the @ComponentScan.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[HTTP code 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404), means no resource found (on the server) for your request, which I think that your controller is not visible(let me say is not scanned) by spring boot.

A simple solution is scanning a parent package in `MockConfig` class, so spring can pick up all beans,

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "edu.lelyak") // assuming that's the parent package in your project
```

if you don't like this approach, you can add the controller's package name in `basePackages`

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"edu.lelyak.controller","edu.lelyak.repository")
```

BTW, you don't have to manually set up `WeatherStationService` in `MockConfig` class, Spring boot can inject a mock for you and automatically reset it after each test method, you should just declare it in your test class:

```
@MockBean
private IStationRepository stationRepository;
```

On the other hand, you should mock `weatherService.getAllStations()` before calling `get("/stations")` in your test method (as you're not running [integration test](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html)), so you can do:

```
List<WeatherStation> myList = ...;
//Add element(s) to your list
 Mockito.when(stationService.getAllStations()).thenReturn(myList);
```

You can find more in :

- [Testing improvements in Spring Boot 1.4](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4)
- [Spring Boot features: Testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)

Comment: For me it turned out to be as simple as missing "/" in starting of the request path. I was trying "v1/user/{id}"  instead of "/v1/user/{id}" in my controller test.

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue. The controller was not getting picked up despite specifying it with `@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)`. This meant all of its mappings were ignored, causing the 404. Adding `@Import(MyController.class)` resolved the issue, but I didn't expect the import to be necessary when I'm already specifying which controller to test.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense but worked for me :D. I'm using Spring boot 2.4.4

Comment: The same worked for me also with @ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyController.class)}

Comment: well this works for my case, thanks for your pointer man, saved a headache for 2.1.6

Comment: I think, ContextConfiguration does not add, but overwrites which classes are put into the context. So as soon as you use ContextConfiguration to add classes to the context (like some security configuration as in my case), you also have to add the controller under test in ContextConfiguration, despite being given in WebMvcTest already. Actually, you can leave out the controller from the WebMvcTest annotation and keep your code DRY.

Comment: However, in the end I added all classes to the value aka controllers attribute of WebMvcTest and removed the ContextConfiguration. At least with Spring 3.1.2, this works, although the documentation of the controllers attribute says that these should be the controllers under test.

Comment: Spring boot 3.1.X Adding import cause this `A circular @Import has been detected`

Comment: I am using spring boot '2.7.18' and this actually worked. I am so surprised though.

Answer (score 11):

After some debugging, it appears that the target controller is simply not registered as a method handler. Spring scans the beans for the presence of `RestController` annotation.

But the problem is that the annotation could be found only if the bean is proxied via **CGLIB**, but for the case when we use `WebMvcTest` it's proxied by **JDK**.

As a result, I searched for the configuration which is responsible for making the choice, and the one was finally found `AopAutoConfiguration`. So when SpringBootTest is used this one is autoloaded when you need `WebMvcTest+PreAuthorize` in your controllers, then simply use:

```
@Import(AopAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: The correct way to import autoconfiguration is using `@ImportAutoConfiguration`.
Alternatively you can use `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`

Comment: @StasKolodyuk `@ImportAutoConfiguration` doesn't work me, which makes sense as it is part of `@WebMvcTest` as well. `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` didn't work for me either. In the end only `@Import(AopAutoConfiguration.class)` from this answer fixed the 404's on the controller with my `@PreAuthorize`-annotated endpoints.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure why your test is not working. But I got another solution which works for me.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new TestController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnCorrectStation() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/stations")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: how you looked to full controller test?

Comment: @nazar_art I cloned you github project but it was full of errors. Not sure if your MockMvc is correct. I would go the easy way and register one controller in your test class like I provided.

Comment: This app has exactly one controller. Also, you need to set up [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) support for your IDE. Without this, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: For IntelliJ you need only install `Lombok plugin` and `enable annotation processor` at settings for the full project.

Comment: The problem with `@SpringBootTest` is that it spins up the entire Spring environment. It's more suited to integration tests. That's why `@WebMvcTest` and other annotations exist. In addition, your tests will run a lot quicker.

Answer (score 4):

I import external configuration class by `@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfig.class)`

When I changed in `MyConfig` annotation `@Configuration` into `@TestConfiguration` it started to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a good answer but I could find one of the causes.

I was using in my tests the `@PreAuthorize` on the RestController.
You can mock the Oauth with [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921028/2387977) on the integration tests that use `SpringBootTest`.  For `SpringBootTest`, this works very well too, but using `SpringBootTest` you load a lot of other resources (like JPA) that is not necessary to do a simple Controller test.

But with `@WebMvcTest` this not works as expected. The use of the [WithMockOAuth2Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921028/2387977) annotation can be enough to stop the 401 error from authentication problem, but after that the WebMvcTest can't find the rest endpoint, returning the 404 error code.

After removing the `@PreAuthorize` on Controller, the test with `WebMvcTest` pass.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45579397/6654475), in my case I had copied and modified the file based on another test, but forgot to **change the name for the controller** on the top of the class, that being the reason why it was not finding the resource, as the error says.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(AnswerCommandController.class)
public class AnswerCommandControllerTest {
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is wondering.

If we don't use `@ContextConfiguration`, `@WebMvcTest` annotation will load the REST controller class. Otherwise, when we use use `@ContextConfiguration`, seems `ContextConfiguration` clear the context REST controller config. We need to add the REST controller to `ContextConfiguration` such as:
`@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockConfig.class, WeatherStationController.class})`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach to the controller test that worked for me.

Assumption: The class `WeatherStationService` is a `@SpringBootApplication`

Then, the test class below should work for you:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(WeatherStationService.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class WeatherStationControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc =  MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnCorrectStation() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/stations")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk();
    }
}
```

With this test setup, you should no longer need the `MockConfig` class.

Comment: I hope the suggestion will be helpful this time and it is not too late.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was about a missing starting slash `/`

I've appended `/` to both `RequestMapping value` and `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder post urlTemplate` parameters as first character.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have to add the controller also to the @ContextConfiguration.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MockConfig.class, WeatherStationController.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75464409/861949), I thought the problem might be with using `ContextConfiguration` to create the proper context.
Also in the [documentations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) for `WebMvcTest` it says:

> Typically @WebMvcTest is used in combination with @MockBean or @Import to create any collaborators required by your @Controller beans.

So I replaced the `ContextConfiguration` with `Import` and it worked.